# How to add additional parameter to resource route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, controller, routes

Is there any way to add additional parameters to laravel resource route so that the url looks like `www.blog.com/blogpost/1` to `www.blog.com/blogpost/1-my-first-blog`.

`blog/{id}` to `blog/{id}-{title}`

I know about basic route parameters that goes like this `blog/{id}/{title}`

Comment: Do like: `Route::resource('blogpost', 'BlogpostController', ['parameters' => [
    'blogpost' => 'whatever'
]]);` That translates to `/blogpost/{whatever}`

Answer (score 2):

Hope can help you

In your routes file:

```
Route::get('blog/{slug}', 'BlogController@show'); // make sure not conflict with resource routes define
```

And then your `BlogController`

```php
 public function show($slug)
    {
        $id = explode($slug, '-')[0]; //get id of post

        // your logic
    }
```

Comment: OP uses `ResourceController` and resource routes! Have you read question properly??

Comment: @HirenGohel I think we need to define new route to handle new url format like `www.blog.com/blogpost/1-my-first-blog`. I read your comment but i think it only change name of params. Not change url format!

Comment: Can you please see `Naming Resource Route Parameters` topic in docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Also OP define this `Is there any way to add additional parameters to laravel resource route` in his question so i think this is not the answer!

Comment: Can you please explain me how we can handle url with format from `blog/{id}` to `blog/{id}-{title}`? Thank you

Comment: Also, I am trying to resolve problem `handle new url format`, by define 1 new route, i think it's a simple way. Need need change other code.

Comment: You are right if we use `get/post` or any other routes! But can we use this solution when we are using resource routes/controller? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable:^4.3
```

Install and configure this pakage then you can simply do `findBySlug($slug)`. But you cannot achieve this this by resource routes.

More info about laravel sluggable can be found [here](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable)

hope this helps.